# Hotkey for Hyperlink in Interactive Console

Tags: pydev

I am trying to rid myself of mouse clicks. I can move by keystroke to the pydev interactive console. I can move by keystroke a hyperlink line. How can I actually invoke the hyperlink by a keystroke (I can do by left clicking the mouse at this point of course but I am trying to avoid that for efficiency).
 Thanks,
  Luke

Answer (score 0):

Try hitting the RETURN key.

Update: Sorry, I retract the glib answer.  I don't think you can do this without modifying the PyDev source code.

There is a key binding setting in preferences for Open Hyperlink, but it doesn't do anything for me, maybe you can get it to work:

W)indow, P)references; Preferences, Keys, OpenHyperlink command, then Binding: (whatever you like, e.g CTRL-ENTER), When: (tried PyDev view, Console view).

Comment: Thank you for replying. THis does not seem to work. I get the cursor blinking in the pydev hyperlink. I hit return. Nothing. I have to mouse click to follow the link... other ideas?